# How to change context path of glassfish using linux

Tags: linux, glassfish-4

I want to change the context-path of application in glassfish using linux.
I cannot access the 4848 of glassfish due to some restrictions, i can only access it thru linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the port for the admin-listener in the **domain.xml** file:

```
<network-listener 
    protocol="admin-listener" 
    port="9000"     // <-- change the port to your needs
    name="admin-listener" 
    thread-pool="admin-thread-pool" 
    transport="tcp">
</network-listener>
```

**Note:** I did not test if the console commands work when you change the admin listener port. So you should test it in you DEV or TEST enviornment before.